# Is a hash function based on multiple nested iterations of HMAC-SHA-256 cryptographically weaker than SHA-512?

Tags: hash, algorithm-design

Let $M$ denote a message.

Choose (arbitrarily or randomly) five **different** sequences of bits (their lengths are allowed to be arbitrary, assuming that our HMAC construction will not exceed the maximum input length for SHA-256). Denote them by $S_i$. For example, we can simply choose “0”, “00”, “000”, “0000” and “00000”.

Consider the following function:  $$\begin{array}{l}
H(M) = H_5 \mathbin\Vert H_6,\\
\end{array}$$

where $$\begin{array}{l}
H_1 = \text{SHA-256}(M),\\
H_2 = \text{HMAC-SHA-256}(M, H_1 \mathbin\Vert S_1),\\
H_3 = \text{HMAC-SHA-256}(M, H_2 \mathbin\Vert S_2),\\
H_4 = \text{HMAC-SHA-256}(M, H_3 \mathbin\Vert S_3),\\
H_5 = \text{HMAC-SHA-256}(M, H_1 \mathbin\Vert H_3 \mathbin\Vert S_4),\\
H_6 = \text{HMAC-SHA-256}(M, H_2 \mathbin\Vert H_4 \mathbin\Vert S_5)\\
\end{array}$$

(assuming that $M$ is the message for HMAC, and the part that ends with $S_i$ is the key).

Is $H(M)$ weaker than $\text{SHA-512}(M)$? If yes, in what aspects?

Comment: "maximum message length of SHA-256"

Comment: Analysis of full designs is off-topic on this website. Could you maybe formulate a broader question?

Comment: @Elias: I meant maximum input length for SHA-256 (as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388177/is-there-a-limit-for-sha256-input))

Comment: I would say this probably depends heavily on the threat model, if it is collision resistance then SHA-512 would be far superior

Comment: The question comes down to state, I *think*. The internal state of SHA-256 is half that of SHA-512 and concatenating two different hashes that depend on half the state doesn't necessarily double the final security of the hash function. So it would be easiest to disprove that doubling the output relying on SHA-256 doesn't double the security provided by the state. If the state is effectively doubled then it comes down to comparing the complexity of the hash-construct with SHA-512, but I'm afraid that will be much harder (I'm freewheeling a bit here).

Comment: I was about to answer, but I realized you haven't said which of the HMAC inputs is the key and which the message. That affects how you can attack this.

Comment: @otus: I edited the question.

Comment: @lyrically wicked: So far I see no attack better than brute force, be it for collision or preimage, even if I suppose that the compression of SHA-256 has the same kind of weaknesses that pleague MD5 and SHA-1. This seems stronger than [previous attempts](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54103/555). Yet, in modern crypto, that's not a valid argument, and the burden of proof (or argument) is on the proposal's side. Independently: there are 6 passes on the message, and only the last two can be run in parallel, and that precludes on-the-fly hashing, which is a very serious practical issue.